# Spring Cloud Stream on Cloud Foundry : Binding a RabbitMq source to a Stream application

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a simple need to deploy a Stream application to our internal cloud foundry instance. The stream has a [RabbitMq queue as the source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/rabbit/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-rabbit) of messages for it, and is defined as below for running it locally on PC:

`stream create myMessageStream --definition "rabbit --rabbit.queues=cloud-stream-source --rabbit.requeue=true --spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost --spring.rabbitmq.port=5672 --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType='text/plain' | task-processor --uri=maven://...`

The application works smooth on PC but in an attempt to set it up on our PaaS platform on PCF, I am unsure how to define the source for the stream.

The RabbitMq service is created on PaaS and just needs binding with stream to make it happen but I lack visibility on how to do it.

I'm following steps to do it for Cloud Foundry from [Spring Docs on SCDF](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_running_the_server_app_locally) but stuck at this stage.

Please share if you know how to do it.

Comment: This can be a very generic question and may help understand how to bind any service as a source @PCF to a Stream? And also to how to bind any PCF Service with a Task that is finally triggered by the Stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one: `export SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES=rabbit` sets up the servies to bind when the stream apps are deployed. 
The property `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_SERVICES` contains the comma separated list of all the services you want your stream app to bind to.

For tasks, you need to use this property `SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES`.

You can refer doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuration_reference) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Ilayaperumal. Looks like I misunderstood this config param at the time when I first referred it as "service type" rather than the "service instance name". So that will solve the binding of services required by Stream app. And I hope we can pass the connection credentials for source in the `stream create` command using environment variables, can't we?

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is supposed to be. The source app should be configurable for any credentials needed with the appropriate property keys. Please give it a try and let us know if you run into issue.